# where is a restricted user's home directory for Nexus 7 (2013 - JB 4.3)

Tags: internal-storage, nexus-7, 4.3-jelly-bean, multi-user, restricted-profiles

**Background:** I have a rooted Google Nexus 7 (2013 - FLO) tablet, which I love.  I have created 2 restricted user accounts for each of my kids.  They both love Minecraft, and with restricted user accounts, they each get their own home directory, where their Minecraft worlds are stored.  This is great for them, because they can't tamper with each other's worlds.  :)  Now that the phone is rooted, I would like to copy their worlds off old devices and into their account space or home directories.

**Question:**  Where is the home directory (or user account storage space) for *restricted* accounts on the new Google Nexus 7 (2013), which is running JellyBean 4.3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are stored in

```
/mnt/shell/emulated/
```

I've just created a restricted profile and it created a new folder in there with the name "10", the main admin users folder is "0". You should be able to copy the files into the relevant place within these folders to get mine craft to pick them up.

(This was done on the 2012 Nexus 7 but I don't think it will be any different)

Comment: Nougat: `/mnt/user/<two_digit_user_id>`

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with Subway Surfers. 
I finally found that profile data was under:

```
/data/user/<user_id_number>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

**Quick answer:**

```
/storage/emulated/<user_id_number>
```

**Details:**

Unless possibly exploring the file-system with root permissions, the primary user *cannot* copy the files around.  It is easiest for the restricted user to use a file explorer or some WiFi uploader, like [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid), to upload the needed files from his or her account.

I'll experiment and report more later, but for now, use AirDroid or similar from the restricted account to upload the needed files.